# Call to undefined method Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder::toArray()

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am new using laravel, and I got this error like this :

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::toArray()
```

this is query builder in laravel

```
$statsMoneyInPlay = DB::table('enginepoker_log.poker')
                    ->selectRaw("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date(ts)*100 as ts)")
                    ->selectRaw("sum(pot + p1pot + p2pot + p3pot + p4pot + p5pot + p6pot + p7pot + p8pot + p9pot) / count(*) As moneyInPlay")
                    ->groupBy("Date(ts)")
                    ->orderBy("Date(ts)")
                    ->toArray();
```

Comment: change it to`->get()->toArray();`

Comment: put get() and I got error like this { SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date(ts)*100 as ts), sum(pot + p1pot + p2pot + p3pot + p4p' at line 1 (SQL: select SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date(ts)*100 as ts), sum(pot + p1pot + p2pot + p3pot + p4pot + p5pot + p6pot + p7pot + p8pot + p9pot) / count(*) As moneyInPlay from enginepoker_log.poker group by Date(ts) order by Date(ts) asc) }

Answer (score 0):

First get() collection and then convert it to array (toArray())

```
$statsMoneyInPlay = DB::table('enginepoker_log.poker')
                                ->selectRaw("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date(ts)*100 as ts)")
                                ->selectRaw("sum(pot + p1pot + p2pot + p3pot + p4pot + p5pot + p6pot + p7pot + p8pot + p9pot) / count(*) As moneyInPlay")
                                ->groupBy("Date(ts)")
                                ->orderBy("Date(ts)")
                                ->get()
                                ->toArray();
```

Comment: i put get() and I got error like this { SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date(ts)*100 as ts), sum(pot + p1pot + p2pot + p3pot + p4p' at line 1 (SQL: select SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date(ts)*100 as ts), sum(pot + p1pot + p2pot + p3pot + p4pot + p5pot + p6pot + p7pot + p8pot + p9pot) / count(*) As moneyInPlay from `enginepoker_log`.`poker` group by `Date(ts)` order by `Date(ts)` asc) }

Answer (score 0):

```
$statsMoneyInPlay = DB::table('enginepoker_log.poker')
    ->selectRaw("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date(ts)*100 as ts)")
    ->selectRaw("sum(pot + p1pot + p2pot + p3pot + p4pot + p5pot + p6pot + p7pot + p8pot + p9pot) / count(*) As moneyInPlay")
    ->groupBy("Date(ts)")
    ->orderBy("Date(ts)")
```

returns an `Eloquent Query Builder instance`. it's like `MySQL` query. It actually **Does Not** fetch data from the database.

You need to execute that query to fetch data from database.

to do so. call `get()` function to the `Eloquent Query Builder instance`.

```
$statsMoneyInPlay = DB::table('enginepoker_log.poker')
    ->selectRaw("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date(ts)*100 as ts)")
    ->selectRaw("sum(pot + p1pot + p2pot + p3pot + p4pot + p5pot + p6pot + p7pot + p8pot + p9pot) / count(*) As moneyInPlay")
    ->groupBy("Date(ts)")
    ->orderBy("Date(ts)")
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: and this is query from native php                                            
    $statsMoneyInPlay = array();

 $sql_query = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Date(ts))*1000 As ts, sum(pot + p1pot + p2pot + p3pot + p4pot + p5pot + p6pot + p7pot + p8pot + p9pot) / count(*) As moneyInPlay
     FROM enginepoker_log.poker
     WHERE dealerId = ".$session->dealerId."
     GROUP BY Date(ts)
     ORDER BY Date(ts) LIMIT 30
     ";

 $resource = Sql::query($sql_query) or die(mysql_error());